# Why spring security context doesn`t persist authenticated custom user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am making small web-store on Java for university project using Spring Boot and WebLogic server. I don`t use Hibernate, only JDBC.
In controller I need to get my current Spring Security User. I made CustomUser that implements UserDetails class and UserDetailsService implementation.

When I login into the server it accepts my credentials, page reloads, but immediately forwards me back to login page. It should redirect me just to /rootPath/ instead.

Here is my Security Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/registration").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/", "/store/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        super.configure(auth);
    }
}
```

Custom User implementation

```
public class CustomUser implements UserDetails {

    private int id = -1;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private ProductCart productCart;

    public CustomUser(int id, String name, String surname, String phone, String email, String password, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
}
```

I tried to permit all requests to my /rootPath/ and get my User directly from Security Context and it showed me anonymousUser, when I login and was redirected to /rootPath/. I think that for some reason Spring or forgets my credentials, or just don't use my custom user as SecurityContext user and still use standart Spring user (for which I don't provide any service). I know for sure that my user loads from database correctly.

Here is my CustomUser class and UserDetailsService implementation (I removed getters and setters)

CustomUser.java

```
public class CustomUser implements UserDetails {

    private int id = -1;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private ProductCart productCart;

    public CustomUser(int id, String name, String surname, String phone, String email, String password, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        productCart = new ProductCart();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        CustomUser customUser = userDao.getByEmail(email);
        if (customUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with email: " + email);
        }
        return customUser;
    }
}
```

Maybe I forgot to configure something or just my realization is wrong in some way?

Comment: You have to populate the `SecurityContextHolder` with the principal data you have got.

Answer (score 1):

You have to populate the `SecurityContextHolder` with the principal information you have fetched. For instance, you can extend `OncePerRequestFilter` and add the following:

```
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
final SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(authentication);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `auto-wiring` the `PasswordEncoder` but where is the bean ? Spring is expecting a bean for `auto-wiring` of type `PasswordEncoder`

Specify the bean in your configuration file - `SecurityConfig` :

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getEncoder(){
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```